# Filtering out elements in array/vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have not used Matlab in a long time and now I'm trying to get back into it. My problem is the following:

I want to filter out elements in a vector with, say, absolute values greater than the mean + two times the standard deviation of the data set. Then I calculate the standard deviation on the remaining series and filter again. I want to repeat this procedure until no further elements need to be filtered out.

I have done the first filtration like this:

```
indices = find(abs(x) > mean(x) + 2*std(x));
x(indices) = [];
```

But I am not quite sure how to get while loop correct after that, having forgotten a lot about Matlab indexing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What step are you having difficulty with? Post your code and ask more specific questions about it. That way it's more likely you'll get an answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this...

```
indices = find(abs(x) > mean(x) + 2*std(x));    
while any(indices)
     x(indices) = [];
     indices    = find(abs(x) > mean(x) + 2*std(x));    
end
```